# SharedArrayBuffer not defined when using Cypress

Tags: ffmpeg, cypress, sharedarraybuffer

I'm using Vite and Cypress for dev and testing

I'm loading ffmpeg, it loads fine on Chrome but on Cypress, it gives this error

```
ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined
```

Apparently, it's caused by cross origin isolation.

I tried disabling web security in `Cypress.json` but it didn't help

Sample code

```js
import { createFFmpeg } from "@ffmpeg/ffmpeg"

const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ log: true })
ffmpeg.load()
```

Is there a workaround?

Minimal Repro
https://github.com/unlocomqx/cypress-ffmpeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a kind of the same problem in my project and I could reproduce your error with your example.

Try to switch back your Cypress Version to 8.5.0 and run the tests with the Electron Browser.
That's my workaround so far...

From Cypress 8.5.0 to 8.6.0 they updated the Electron Version from 13.2.0 to 14.1.0:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#8-6-0

I'll make a post and ask for help in the Cypress forum and link this post.

Link to the Cypress Issue: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/19912

Thx for the example repo.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever server you are using, it needs to sends the following headers to the client.

Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin

Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp

For security reasons, SharedArrayBuffer are disabled without these headers present in the server response.

Comment: But your app is inside the cypress iframe so these headers won't help.